# How do I obtain a variance-covariance matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance, variance, bsxfun

I am trying to maintain the variance-covariance matrix of a 10 asset portfolio of stocks. The data is represented by a column of returns for 10 stocks. I.e.

```
Stock A Stock B

Return 1 Return 1

Return 2 Return 2

Etc Etc
```

When I upload my data I have tried the `cov(data)` function but it will not work. I keep receiving this message:

> "Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'dataset'.
>
> Error in cov (line 154) xc = bsxfun(@minus,x,sum(x,1)/m); % Remove meanUndefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'dataset'.
>
> Error in cov (line 154) xc = bsxfun(@minus,x,sum(x,1)/m); % Remove mean"

My question is how do I proceed with finding the average returns of each stock and the variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: Please add the code producing these errors.

Comment: The source of the error seems to be that `data` is a dataset instead of a matrix.

Comment: I've found a way around it by defining my data input as a numeric matrix as opposed to column vectors. The problem now is that Matlab will not read my first row in every column (i.e. the names of the stocks). What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Dataset objects are being deprecated, so you should consider using tables instead.  But with the dataset you want

```
>> dataAsMatrix = double(NameOfYourDataSetVariable);
>> cov(dataAsMatrix)
>> mean(dataAsMatrix)
```

To convert to a table use `dataset2table',

```
>> dataAsTable = dataset2table(NameOfYourDataSetVariable);
```

Then for some operations you can do things like

```
>> varfun(@mean,dataAsTable)
```

Although for `cov` I think you still need to extract the data

```
>> cov(dataAsTable{:,:})
```